# Cross thread operation not valid--Change grid cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

**Hello developers,** again here with new problem !!
In my thread program I was facing problem when I was changing a value of control.
**Problem was: Cross-thread operation not valid.**

Yes..I got solution with below function that let me allow to access control in threading.

```
delegate void SetControlValueCallback(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue);
private void SetControlPropertyValue(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue)
{
    if (oControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetControlValueCallback d = new SetControlValueCallback(SetControlPropertyValue);
        oControl.Invoke(d, new object[] { oControl, propName, propValue });                
    }
    else
    {
        Type t = oControl.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in props)
        {
            if (p.Name.ToUpper() == propName.ToUpper())
            {
                p.SetValue(oControl, propValue, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I need to change value of control(**like change text of lable**) I use that function
**SetControlPropertyValue(_form.lblImportFiles, "Text", "Importing...");** like this and its change the value.
***Now..I want to change value of grid cell or need to play with its Rows property..etc..***

How can I do that? I am totally blind here..Take me out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to set value in Datagridview, then try this,

```
private void ChangeGridUploadStatus(DataGridView dgv)
{
if (!dgv.InvokeRequired)
{
dgv["ColumnName", index].Value = "ok";
}
else
{
dgv.Invoke(new ChangeGridUploadStatusHandler(ChangeGridUploadStatus), dgv);
}
}
delegate void ChangeGridUploadStatusHandler(DataGridView dgv);
```